# How can I detect when a view is hidden by action bar

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have an action bar and I have set the theme as overlay and made it (semi) transparent.
I am trying to detect when a specific view (when scrolling up) goes bellow the action bar.
Using a solution like:
`view.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)`
does not work because the action bar has a height (I get it with `actionBar.getHeight()` but the scrolling view gets all the screen. So I have to scroll way up the action bar outside of the window in order to be considered hidden.
Is there a way to detect when a view is bellow or it's bottom passed the action bar's bottom effectively?
I guess the solution must be something like:

```
if(screen.top + actionBar.getHeight() > view.getBottom) {  
//invisible
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there a solution?